# Change database encoding in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES `utf8`;', $link);
```

is the same that

`$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';`

OR

`$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';`

in "application\config\database.php" on Codeigniter?
If not, how can I do it in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the CI database driver, you will see that the function setting the char set and collation is called with `db_set_charset($charset, $collation)`

And looking further into that function will reveal this function (from the mysqli driver):

```
function _db_set_charset($charset, $collation)
{
    static $use_set_names;

    if ( ! isset($use_set_names))
    {
        // mysqli_set_charset() requires MySQL >= 5.0.7, use SET NAMES as fallback
        $use_set_names = (version_compare(mysqli_get_server_info($this->conn_id), '5.0.7', '>=')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    if ($use_set_names)
    {
        return @mysqli_query($this->conn_id, "SET NAMES '".$this->escape_str($charset)."' COLLATE '".$this->escape_str($collation)."'");
    }
    else
    {
        return @mysqli_set_charset($this->conn_id, $charset);
    }
}
```

This basically means that if you use MySQL 5.0.7 or newer, mysqli_set_charset() is used instead of 'SET NAMES'.

If you need to change that behavior , I suggest you create your own database driver.